# Update references each time LaTeX compiles document

Tags: cross-referencing, compiling

When I use my TeXnicCenter and hit the compile button I want that all references are updated ... So I don't have to compile 3 times till all those references update. Because with a bunch of pictures and 22 pages it takes my pc almost a minute each time. So it would be perfect to do all the stuff except creating pdf but a dvi 3 times and than create the pdf.

Is there a way to do that? I bet most of you LaTeX users are annoyed by that too.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is no need that references are correct each time you want to preview the document; if you compile often, just do it once. When you add a citation or a cross reference, the next time it won't be correct, but the process will eventually stabilize.

Comment: `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}` reduces compilation time also...

Comment: @egreg Would you like to answer, or do you think some duplicate exist?

Comment: Are your pictures heavy? Because it should not take that long unless their weight is unnecessary high.

Answer (score 1):

When writing the document, it's seldom necessary to have references correct each time: adding or moving around text will almost certainly make some of them incorrect.

Also compiling frequently is not really needed, but with fast machines it's not such a big problem.

The advantage of LaTeX is that cross references are guaranteed to be right, unless the “Rerun to get cross-references right” message appears.

Just do the

```
latex
bibtex
latex
latex
```

route when you *really* need that cross-references and citations are fully correct.

If you have many images, adding the `draft` option to `\documentclass` or to the call to `graphicx` helps in reducing compilation time.